# Rails: Multiple if conditions in validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, if-statement

Using: Rails 3.0.3

I have validations such as this one:

```
  validates_numericality_of :person_weight_kg, :greater_than => 0, :message => "value_must_be_number_over_zero", :if => :bmi_calculation?, :if => :is_metric?
```

That I would like to validate for multiple if-conditions (such as in the example). But it seems, however, that Rails treats these statements as OR. One returns false and one returns true which makes the validation go through.

So, how do I check that this validation fulfills BOTH if-statements (bmi_calculation AND is_metric)?

Comment: It also doesn't treat them as OR. The second :if overrides the first one.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use a lambda as the `if` condition:

```
validates_numericality_of :person_weight_kg, 
  if: -> record { record.bmi_calculation? && record.is_metric? }
```

Comment: It doesn't work in Rails 5. Do you have any solution?

Comment: maybe because it should declare the parameter inside the lambda block `if: ->  { |record| record.bmi_calculation? && record.is_metric? }`